Send calls from non-contacts directly to voicemail
I want to send all calls from numbers not in my contact list directly to voicemail.
I don't want to block them completely because I do get relevant calls from other people now and then.
Note that this is not a question about unknown numbers in the sense numbers not registered in a public directory.
What I've tried:

Checked my phone's native settings in the Phone app, but couldn't find an option to send other callers to voicemail.
Installed Truecaller, but it only offers options to block calls from outside my contact list, not send them to voicemail.
Looked through my phone's Do Not Disturb settings, but it gets complicated when I also want to silence my contacts at night.

My goal is to have these calls go straight to voicemail without blocking them entirely, as I still want to receive their voicemail messages and have the option to call them back if needed.
Device: Google Pixel 8
OS: Android 14

According to this post in Wikihow adding a number to the blocking list should still allow the user to leave a voicemail message.

I wonder if How can I send incoming calls from unknown numbers directly to voicemail? can be modified to filter by contacts.

Thanks @Robert, I'm trying this now. There is no information in the settings stating that 'block' in this context means 'send to voicemail'. I'm thinking I might have to configure my carrier to direct to voicemail when i reject a call. I'll test it.

@AndrewT. I was hoping I wouldn't need a custom automation app for it. It feels so basic :)

What if you created a custom contact group Google Contacts, added all your known contacts to this group, and used Do Not Disturb mode with custom exceptions to allow calls only from this group? And then calls from non-contacts will go to voicemail when Do Not Disturb is active. Let me know if I explained myself well and this makes any sense to you:)

I understand what you mean @Lillian. But I would have to update the list continuously. I feel there should be an easier way.
